# Copy a list in "onTap" method

Tags: list, flutter, dart, memory, riverpod

I want to update the list items' values in the `onTap` method to true and false and vice versa to change some widgets according to the item's value if it is true or false,
so, is it okay to do something like this?

I mean, is it okay to copy a list inside onTap or it is not a good practice for the memory.

```
 onTap: () {
             List<bool> copyItems = [...items];
             copyItems[ind] = !copyItems[ind];
             ref.read(openFaqAnsRef.notifier).newList = copyItems;
           },
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you mean, but:

Would it not be simpler to add a parameter to the `copyItems` that switches that value?

Besides, copying all of the items of a list can be devastating to the performance of your app. Imagine You have thousands/hundreds of items and someone presses that button 2/3/4 times in a row.